# How to call a function at client machine in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, function, dll, client

I have a website in asp.net, only allow registered user to access it. Each registered user will get a library to put into his machine. When that user click on a button on website, it will call to a function in that library. But I don't know how to call this function. Can you give me some guide about it?

Comment: What kind of library you want to put to your client's machine (computer)?

Comment: I haven't done any Silverlight development, but depending on how it's sand-boxed on the client machine, it could act as a proxy to the library. Other than that, ActiveX?

Comment: Dynamic library. I think my question is same to BitDefender do with their website, when call a function in local machine to scan online. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

In most of case, i define a click handler function in my codebehind, and then pass handler function's name to OnClick attribute of the control i want to handle.

Comment: I do it too. But I think when call in code behind, it will call function of library at server, not at client machine.